# C# Producer/Consumer implementation issue

Tags: c#

I have a producer-consumer class as following.

```
public class ProducerConsumer<T> where T : class
    {
        private Thread _workerThread;
        private readonly Queue<T> _workQueue;
        private readonly object _lockObject = new object();
        private readonly Action<T> _workCallbackAction;
        private ManualResetEvent _workerWaitSignal;

        public ProducerConsumer(Action<T> action)
        {               
            _workCallbackAction = action;
            _workQueue = new Queue<T>();                
        }

        private void DoWork()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                T workItemToBeProcessed = default(T);
                bool hasSomeWorkItem = false;

                lock (_lockObject)
                {
                    hasSomeWorkItem = _workQueue.Count > 0;

                    if (hasSomeWorkItem)
                    {
                        workItemToBeProcessed = _workQueue.Dequeue();
                        if (workItemToBeProcessed == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (hasSomeWorkItem)
                {
                    if (_workCallbackAction != null)
                    {
                        _workCallbackAction(workItemToBeProcessed);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _workerWaitSignal.WaitOne();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for signal.");
                }
            }
        }

        public void EnQueueWorkItem(T workItem)
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                _workQueue.Enqueue(workItem);
                _workerWaitSignal.Set();
            }
        }

        public void StopWork(ManualResetEvent stopSignal)
        {
            EnQueueWorkItem(null);
            _workerThread.Join();
            _workerWaitSignal.Close();
            _workerWaitSignal = null;
            if (stopSignal != null)
            {
                stopSignal.Set();
            }
        }

        public void ReStart()
        {
            _workerWaitSignal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            _workerThread = new Thread(DoWork) { IsBackground = true };
            _workerThread.Start();
        }
    }
```

and i am using this in the following way:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private RecordProducerConsumer<string> _proConsumer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _proConsumer = new RecordProducerConsumer<string>(DoAction);
        }


        private bool restart=true;
        private int item = 0;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (restart)
            {
                _proConsumer.ReStart();
                restart = false;
            }

            item++;
            _proConsumer.EnQueueWorkItem(item.ToString());

        }

        private void DoAction(string str)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(str);
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            _proConsumer.StopWork(mre);
            mre.WaitOne();
            restart = true;
        }

        private void Stop(ManualResetEvent mre)
        {
            mre.WaitOne();          
        }
    }
```

My problem or what I can not understand is when I click `Start` button I am adding only one item and it `Dequeue` that item but keeps on running the loop so I see lot of `"Waiting for signal."` print outs on the `Output` window in `Visual Studio`.

Why does it not stop on `_workerWaitSignal.WaitOne();` in `DoWork()` method , why is it running all the time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. It makes hardly any sense to output 'Waiting for issue' *after* executing the wait. Consider moving the write *before* the actual wait.
2. You are using a `ManualResetEvent` — as its name indicates, it requires a *manual reset* to revert from the *signalled* state. However, I can't see a call to `Reset` in your code.
3. To avoid other concurrency issues (e.g. a race condition when when resetting the event while other thread set the event after enqueuing another work item), consider using a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) for your scenario instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this... I could be wrong...but that is all i could figure out by reading through your code. Hope this helps :)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (restart)
        {
            restart = false;
            _proConsumer.ReStart();                
        }

        item++;
        _proConsumer.EnQueueWorkItem(item.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the code thoroughly, but I can venture a guess that you meant to use an [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) (which resets automatically after some `WaitOne()` is released) rather than a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) (which stays set until you explicitly call `Reset()`).

Also, is there any reason you're not using .NET's [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) ? It's the framework implementation of the producer/consumer pattern, and it works very well.

Comment: I see. You could try copy-pasting from the reference source, worth a shot.